# Checking for backwards compatibility- an easier way?

Tags: android, google-play

I am about to release my first app and targeted lollipop when writing it in the hope that the uptake would of been greater by the time I was done. As well all know, it is still awful.

In my build.gradle I have this line:

```
android {
    signingConfigs {
    }
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.xxx.xxxx.toolbox"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 7
        versionName "1.15"
    }
```

If I change the min SDK version to 19, the app will try and install on a device running API level 19. It crashes, but does not give me any feedback as to why (I have obviously used some methods from higher APIs). Is there any way to quickly figure out which methods I have used that need to be changed?

thanks,
Matt

Comment: "but does not give me any feedback as to why" -- it will in LogCat.

Comment: I am using Android studio and it didn't with the lower API device connected. With my nexus it usually does.

Comment: Android Studio's LogCat tool has issues. If you are not seeing error messages with the per-app filtering, disable that filter and just set up an Error severity filter. Or, use the Android Device Monitor, or **`adb logcat`**, if needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you set `minSdkVersion` to some version and recompile your application, Lint should automatically mark all instances where you use higher API as errors. That is, unless you annotate it with `@TargetApi`.

Also, if your application crashes, check LogCat. There will be an exception describing what went wrong and where.

Comment: Should lint run automatically? the app crashes on my samsung tab but nothing is shown in AS.

Comment: Lint is run automatically during compilation. If you change `minSdkVersion`, you need to clean and rebuild the whole appliction otherwise no checks will be done.

Comment: You may specifically want to run a Rebuild All (from the Build menu) to force a full rebuild of everything.